# Only display defined product tags thumbnails in Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

This code below checks if a product has a tag. If it does, then it checks to see if the tags are any of the ones from an array. Then it spits out all the tags of that product.

What I would like this code to do is to only show the tags that I specify.

I am using the tags 'compostable','biodegradable','recycled','recyclable' as images to display to the user that this product has green credentials.

However, I am also using many other tags which I do not ever want the user to see. I only want the customer to see these 4 tags if they exist, sometimes only one of these tags may be relevant, sometimes up to 4.

How would I do this with the below?

```
//lets show the tag images
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'showTagImages', 6 );

function showTagImages() {
    $current_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );

    //only start if we have some tags
    if ( $current_tags && ! is_wp_error( $current_tags ) ) { 

        if( has_term( array( 'compostable','biodegradable','recycled','recyclable' ), 'product_tag') ) {
                //style it.
                echo '<style type="text/css">
                ul.productTags{background:rgba(60, 184, 120, 0.70); margin:0; padding:10px; display:inline-block; list-style:none; text-align:center; border-radius: 3px; width:39%; }
                .productTags li{margin:0; padding:5px; display:inline-block; }
                .productTags img{margin:0; padding:0;}
                </style>';

                //create a list to hold our tags
                echo '<ul class="productTags">';

                //for each tag we create a list item
                foreach ($current_tags as $tag) {

                    $tag_title = $tag->name; // tag name

                    echo '<li><img alt="'.$tag_title.'" src="/img/tags/'.$tag_title.'.png"></li>';
                }

                echo '</ul>';}

         }
    }
```